# Not showing Events per Client in Google Optimize <> GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, ab-testing, google-optimize

We encountered a weird behavior after integrating Google Optimize with GA4.
The AB test is running, but we see "0" in the “Calculated Events per Client” column.

**Did anyone have a similar situation?**

Context:

- The objective in the 1st screenshot below is a GA4 Conversion, which is tested and works as expected
- we also have another objective on “Pageviews” that populates the “Calculated Events per Client” column with values (see the second screenshot)
- we think a possible explanation relates to the number of decimals GO shows. But when we computed the numbers, we concluded that we still should be able to see at least 0.01 events per client

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSPnG.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJDGb.png)

- we tested the events. They work just fine
- GA4 is also reporting as expected

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm seeing something similar on my site.

GA4 is working fine.
Google Optimize says it is installed properly. However, it is recording 0 experiment sessions. I'm not sure why your screenshot refers to "Experiment Clients." I've never seen that before. Is it a server-side experiment?

Our GA4 account is setup with server-side tagging, however we doing just a regular client-side Optimize experiment.